# reduce gap between figure and text

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure

code -

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.50\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{Thesis-2/Chapter2/Figures/py.pdf} 
% \caption{Caption1}
\label{fig:wrapfig}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

[image]

tell me how can I reduce the gap between the image and the text below it

Comment: `\begin{wrapfigure}[6]` although probab;y the space is in your image

Comment: If you'd use package `wrapfig2`, there already shouldn't such a gap, unless the image includes the white space below the image. If you are using package `wrapfig`, there would be an optional argument to set the number of narrow lines. See the manual for more information. If you would show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) instead of a code snippet only, real answers could be given.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: NO gap in image.

The above shown is the working example only, it has text above and below it, as shown in image